# Replace words in a string, ignoring quotes and matching the whole word

Tags: python, regex, replace

I know this question is very similar to other questions on here, however I have not been able to adapt a working answer out of any of the solutions.  Apologies!

I am looking to replace words in a string, ignoring anything in quotes, and matching the whole word.

i.e. good evening my name is Tommy, I like football and "my" favourite sports is myfootball.

I would like to replace 'my', for instance, but I do not want to replace the "my" or 'my' in "myfootball".

The words I want to replace will be read from a list.

Thanks,

Comment: wrap your match in word boundaries.  `\bmy\b`

Comment: @roippi This doesn't work as well when selecting words from a list?  Unless I've done it wrong.

Comment: have you looked into Regular Expressions?

Comment: Yes, it works on words in a list, provided your implementation is correct.  Show your code.

Comment: @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur I have, I can't make a whole regex solution for the entire match.  I've got two regex lambda functions, that 1) ignores anything in brackets, and 2) matches whole words.  But can't put them together, and it is very wishy-washy code.

Comment: @roippi for words in list: replace(words,replacement).  I've tried putting \b in before/after the name of the element I am replacing, but it didn't ever work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'good evening my name is Tommy, I like football and "my" favourite sports is myfootball'
>>> re.sub(r"\ my "," your ", s)
'good evening your name is Tommy, I like football and "my" favourite sports is myfootball'
```

or the `str.replace` function:

```
>>> s.replace(' my ',' your ')
'good evening your name is Tommy, I like football and "my" favourite sports is myfootball'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [84]: re.sub('\s+"|"\s+'," ",s) # sub a " preceded by a space or a "  followed by a space
Ot[84]: 'good evening my name is Tommy"s, I like football and my favourite sports is myfootball.'


In [88]: re.sub(r'"(my)"', r'\1', s)
Out[88]: 'good evening my name is Tommy, I like football and my favourite sports is my football.'

In [89]: re.sub(r'"(\w+)"', r'\1', s)
Out[89]: 'good evening my name is Tommy, I like football and my favourite sports is my   football.'
```